# multiple rails engines talking to one mySQL server for horizontally scaling application servers

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, horizontal-scaling

I've seen pictures like [this](http://discovr.info/2011/07/scaling-a-rails-webservice-on-awsec2-for-a-1-iphone-and-ipad-app/) where multiple rails engines write to a single mySQL server.

1)  Is this possible?  Or does Rails want each application server to write to one database server?

2)  If this is possible, how is it accomplished?  Are there queues and a scheduler between the application servers and the write database server?

Comment: look at https://github.com/tchandy/octopus

Comment: I'm not sure if you are trolling with this question, or really do have no idea how mysql and other RDBMS's work.

Comment: I have looked at Octopus, but it says it is for sharding where multiple databases are used by the same rails application.  I.E. One to Many as opposed to Many to One.

Comment: @datasage - I'm not trolling.  Every so often we all ask dumb questions, maybe this is one?

Comment: Mysql can handle multiple databases and connections. So yes, you can connect multiple rails apps to the same mysql server. The application server doesnt do any managment of reads/writes. Mysql will.

Comment: You can also connect multiple Rails instances of the same application to the same database. So you could have 4 web servers, connecting to 1 MySQL server, using the same database.

Comment: But that isn't horizontal scaling.  Horizontal scaling is spreading reads (or in sharding, reads and writes) over many servers.  This question is unconstructive.

Answer (score 0):

Scaling a mysql db is a pretty difficult thing to do, but its certainly been done plenty of times and there are a lot of best practices out there for you to take advantage of. The first thing you should know is that before you worry about scaling writes for a while yet, you probably need to scale your reads first.

Scaling reads can be done fairly easily using [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html). There are several tools out there that make managing replication a lot easier such as [Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/). Generally speaking many web severs can connect to many databases (as suggested by others), however you quickly run into scale issues once you have a lot of traffic, connections or whatever other action you are performing that generates load on the server.

As replicated severs are read only, you need to manage which sever you connect to depending on the action you're performing. I.e. if you had a users table, when creating, updating or deleting users you need to use the "write" database (the primary "source" sever) but when reading the user table, you can use one of the read replicas. This reduces the load on the primary write sever (allowing it to deal with even more writes) and as you can have multiple read databases behind a load balancer, you can get away with this structure for a very long time and scale reads across tens of database severs before you'll hit any significant issues (however most apps get away with 1-3).

There are situations where you will need to use your write database for read actions (although you should avoid it as much as possible) as the read replicas can be slightly behind the write dbs due to latency in replicating the write db queries, however most of the time you should be able to code knowing that there is the possibility that the read db is delayed (i.e. queue actions a reasonable period of time such that the updates will propagate across all the read severs) and simply use one of your read dbs rather than the write db.

Beyond this the key items to work on are ensuring you have efficient indexes and applying other best practices around maintaining a sensible data structure. You might also want to consider having 3 distinct "groups" of database servers. I generally like to have write, read and "stats" db groups. The write group for create, update and delete operations (as well as select for update), the read for general read items that must return their results quickly, and stats for anything that is going to be under high load and that you do not rely on for a prompt response (this keeps heavy queries that are not time sensitive away from your read db that you need quick responses from for general reads)

Once you get into a situation where you can no longer buy larger hardware and you're near maxing out your write capacity, you'll need to look into sharding, however that will take a lot of traffic / data (so dont worry about it unless you've done all of the above already).